# Why can't Mythbuntu play DVDs but vlc can?

Tags: dvd, mythbuntu

I did a clean install of Mythbuntu 14.04. Everything (not for my LCD Display) worked fine.

I configured the backend and then I wanted to test mythbuntu. Just playing a normal DVD.
But it won't!

It just say:

```
could not open /dev/dvd
```

But when I use VLC it just works fine. I haven't changed anything till now.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the /dev directory and noticed that while there's no dvd node there is a node called "cdrom".  I went to:

Setup ->
Media Settings ->
Videos Settings ->
Player Settings

and set "DVD Drive:" to "/dev/cdrom".

You could also go to VLC Media Player and go to Media -> "Open Disc..." and see what value it's using for "Disc device" and use that in Mythtv.